# ASP.NET, IIS and COM

Tags: asp.net, iis, com

I'm not that familiar with COM and was hoping that someone out there, who is, could help verify what I have below is correct.

If I have two completely separate Requests (request 1 & request 2), then this creates two separate instances of my WebApplication.  So far so boring.

If each instance then contacts the SAME web service, then presumably two instances of the Web Service are also instantiated.

This is where it gets interesting.

These web services create a .NET assembly which then references an in-process (registered via regsvr32) COM-dll (via Interop).

Is my diagram correct?

[image]

This COM-DLL connects to the database, performs a query, returns data to the web service which then returns the data in JSON to the client.  All done AJAXy.

The other question I have is - is this okay performance-wise?  I don't see why it shouldn't scale, and be able to return data to the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems OK as a logical pattern. But, as always. the devil is in the detail.

This all hinges on the implementation of your Services use of COM components and specifically the COM components handling of threads. If your COM components are thread-safe and marked to use an MTA (Multi threaded apartment) you should be OK. However many COM objects are marked as STA (and so use the Single Threaded Apartment)

In relation to "is this okay performance-wise?", then if your COM component is an STA (which it will be if it was created in VB 6.0) you will have to do a bit of thread untangling (otherwise all your service requests will queue up and performance will get worse under load.)

This article explains both the problem and the solution to this (for ASMX services)...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163544.aspx

..and solution if you're using WCF services...

http://blogs.catalystss.com/blogs/scott_seely/archive/2007/09/27/203.aspx